# How to count traffic on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, traffic

how to count traffic that application sends or receive data on device only in my program. Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing program? Or you just want to count traffic for a program downloaded from app store?

Comment: What class are you using to download data?

Comment: Object with method `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<#(NSURL *)url#>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you wanted analytics or actual bytes in/out traffic data....

If you looking for analytics check out Flurry http://www.flurry.com/
and Crittercism https://www.crittercism.com/